# f.date_select for day only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker

In rails, I am using a date_select for a form. I need only the day of the months to show up, but for some reason I cannot get them to work.

```
<%= f.date_select :filing_date, discard_month:true, discard_year:true, prompt: "Select Year" %>
```

The above code is what I am trying. When I discard day and month/year, it then works for showing the month and the year.

Please let me know if there is a different way to get Day to show up in the form.

Comment: update: I only notice it when I discard_month

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Rails apidoc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select),

:discard_month - Set to true if you don’t want to show a month select. This includes the month as a hidden field instead of showing a select field. Also **note that this implicitly sets :discard_day to true.**

Could you show the month but just make it read only?

Comment: I cant since this is part of a form that people need to select the month and specific day started on something specific.

Comment: I thought you wanted to discard the month? I'm not sure exactly what your form is trying to do.